# How can I identify an integer promotion and a demotion in C?

Tags: c, type-conversion, integer-promotion

I am learning C, and integer promotion and the term *demotion* is new to me.
I have read in the C Standard (C17) about the C type conversions and the integer promotion, but I don't know how to identify an integer promotion, and I don't know anything about demotion.

For example, if I have these lines of code:

```
...
unsigned char x;
int y;
long int z;
int aux; //Auxiliary variable

x = 'c';
y = 1;
z = 2;

aux = x;
aux = y;
aux = z;

aux = x + y; // ZX
aux = y + z;
...
```

Where do I have integer promotion?  Because from what I know, in the line of code commented with `ZX`, I have integer promotion, but only in that line, but I'm not sure; can you clarify it for me?

And can you give me examples of when *demotion* exists? Because the C Standard does not clarify.

Comment: `z = 2;` is a promotion; the type of `2` is `int`, so converting that to `long` changes the type to `long`.  `x = 'c';` is a demotion; the type of `'c'` is `int` (yes, [really](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4)!) so assigning that to `x` converts the `int` to `unsigned char`.

Comment: IP = Internet Protocol. Please don't invent new, confusing abbreviations.

Comment: @Lundin In the not-so-open-source scene, IP is "intellectual property"...

Comment: At least in the case of variables the compiler should warn about a "narrowing" conversion at sufficiently high warning levels (gcc: -Wall -Wextra -pedantic, VC: /W4), which I would recommend. I suppose that the compiler stays silent with `char c = 'c';` though which is provably correct.

Comment: As some of your answers already explain, "demotion" is not a formally defined term in C.  It can perhaps be understood as the opposite of "promotion" in some sense, but we can best address your question about demotion if you provide some context to help us understand what was meant by it in the source where you saw it.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not my specialty, but let me try:

```
unsigned char x;
int y;
long int z;
int aux; //Auxiliar variable

x='c';
y=1;
z=2;    // Very subtle promotion here. 2 is an int, and is promoted to long int to fill z.

aux=x;  // Value of x, which is a char, is PROMOTED to int, to fill aux
aux=y;  // Both left and right sides are int, no promotion/demotion
aux=z;  // Z is a long int, is demoted to fill aux.

aux=x+y; // x(char) is PROMOTED for addition, to match other operand y(int)
aux=y+z; // y(int) is promoted to match longer type z(long int). The result(long int) is then demoted to match assignment aux.
```

I try not to over-rely on promotion rules when programming.

Comment: Strictly, `x = 'c';` is a 'demotion' — the type of `'c'` is `int` (contrast with C++ where the type is `char`) so the `int` value is converted to `unsigned char`.

Comment: I think you should remove the line "I could be wrong about this". It will just confuse visitors...

Answer (score 3):

Integer promotion is a formal C term, but there exists no formal or even informal term called "demotion". Please check [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules) to learn about integer conversion rank, integer promotion and the usual arithmetic conversions.

The closest thing to demotion is "conversion during assignment", which can go from a larger type to a smaller or vice versa. This happens during assignment, in case the types of the operands differ (6.5.16.1):

> In *simple assignment* (=), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

As for how the actual conversions are carried out, see C17 6.3.1.3.

---

Regarding where you have integer promotions/implicit conversions in your code:

- `x = 'c';` Conversion during assignment, from the type of `'c'` which is `int`, into `unsigned char`.
- `z = 2;` Conversion during assignment, from the type of `2` which is `int`, into `long`.
- `aux = x;` Conversion during assignment, from `unsigned char` to `int`.
- `aux = z;` Conversion during assignment, from `long` to `int`.

  Conversions to signed types involves implementation-defined behavior, so it can be a possible bug if the larger value cannot fit in the smaller type.
- `aux = x + y;` The usual arithmetic conversions, including integer promotion of `x` to `int`.
- `aux = y + z;` The usual arithmetic conversions, turning `y` into `long`. Then conversion during assignment, converting back to `int`. Again, possible bug here.

(Some subtle stuff in the last example: in case `y + z` would result in a value that would overflow an `int` but not a `long`, that overflow doesn't actually happen here, because of the `long` conversion before addition. There would be a value loss upon conversion back to `int` but merely implementation-defined behavior and not undefined behavior overflow.)

Comment: Perhaps "conversion during assignment", which I sometimes see spelled "assignment conversion", though not formally. But you've already given the definition of "lvalue conversion", and it never involves any narrowing, so not "lvalue conversion during assignment".  Any lvalue conversion involved in evaluating an assignment expression is logically separate from conversion of the value of the right-hand operand to the type of the left-hand operand.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Qualifiers are part of the type, as demonstrated by this answer. The assignment rules alone only mentions which qualifiers that are valid for each operand, not what will happen to them. For example `volatile int z; ... x = (y=z);` - why should this code force the compiler to generate a write instruction to `x` in case `x` isn't used by the code? It doesn't, since the type of `(y=z)` is `int` and not `volatile int`.

Comment: Yes, so?  Your claim is that "lvalue conversion during assignment" is the closest thing C has to "integer demotion".  And my objection is that "lvalue conversion" has no part in anything that can reasonably be called "demotion".  In particular, dropping type qualifiers is not a demotion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Just read the quoted parts. "an lvalue... is converted to the value stored in the designated object". Which includes a conversion to a narrower type if that's the type of the designated object. "The type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion."

Comment: No, @Lundin, "convert[ing] to the value stored in the designated object" is about the object designated by the lvalue.  Take the expression `x = y`.  Lvalue conversion applies to the sub-expression `y`, converting it to the value stored in the object that `y` designates.  **That value has the same type as `y`** or an unqualified version of that type, never a narrower type.  If necessary, there will be a separate, subsequent conversion to the type of `x`, according to the rules of the assignment operator, but that's not an lvalue conversion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Lvalue conversion _is_ still one form of implicit conversion happening... but I suppose as you say, it isn't relevant for the narrowing part which the question focused on, so maybe bringing it up will just needlessly confuse the reader. I removed the parts about lvalue conversion in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The term *demotion* is not defined in the C Standard, it is only used once in the C17 Standard in the **Annex J - Portability issues**, which is informative only, not a normative part of the Standard. The phrase is not a definition, it just hints that *demotion* may happen when converting a value from one floating point type to another, presumably with a smaller domain:

> **Annex J**
> (informative)
> **Portability issues**
> 1 This annex collects some information about portability that appears in this International Standard.
>
> **J.1 Unspecified behavior**
> [...]
> **J.2 Undefined behavior**
> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
> [...]
> — Demotion of one real floating type to another produces a value outside the range that can be represented (6.3.1.5).

The word is not used in the linked section:

> **6.3.1.5 Real floating types**
> 1 When a value of real floating type is converted to a real floating type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined. Results of some implicit conversions may be represented in greater range and precision than that required by the new type (see 6.3.1.8 and 6.8.6.4).

As stated in the annex, which is only informative, *demotion* happens for example when storing a `double` value to a `float` variable where its value cannot be represented by the `float` type. A typical case is found in a classic programming test:

```
float amount = 0.10;  // implicit conversion from double to float
```

Comment: By demotion, the annex means any conversion from a wider floating type to a narrower type, regardless of the value being converted. Also, the annex says nothing about the (expected and normal) loss of precision that happens upon demotion, it only specifies what happens when the result is out of *range* for the target type. Not that it matters anyway.

Comment: And  even "narrow" or "narrower" or "narrowing" is only used a few times. In the C++ standard, "narrowing conversion" is a technical term defined in 9.4.5/7.

Comment: Annex J is just an informative summary though. It is not normative, it does not define terms.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such as "demotion" of integers in C, but there are promotions.  I believe you're confusing promotion and demotion with *conversion*.

An **integer promotion** occurs when an integer type smaller than `int` is used in an expression, where in most cases it will be *promoted* to either `int` or `unsigned int`.  This is spelled out in section 6.3.1.1p2 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned
> int may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than `int` or `unsigned int`) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>   the rank of int and unsigned int.
> - A bit-field of type `_Bool`, `int`, `signed int`, or `unsigned int`.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
> by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`;
> otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the
> *integer promotions*. All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions.

This differs from a **conversion**, which occurs when *any* type changes to another type, whether the new type is larger or smaller than the original type.

Now applying this to your sample code:

```
x = 'c';
```

The assignment operator converts the right operand to the type of the left operand.  Character constants have type `int`, so the assignment performs a conversion from `int` to `unsigned char`

```
y = 1;
```

Decimal integer constants with no suffix have type `int`, so no conversion or promotion here.

```
z = 2;
```

This assignment performs a conversion from `int` to `long int`.

```
aux = x;
```

This assignment performs a conversion from `unsigned char` to `int`.

```
aux = y;
```

Both sides have the same type, so no conversion.

```
aux = z;
```

This assignment performs a conversion from `long int` to `int`.

```
aux = x + y; //ZX
```

Looking at the `+` operator first, the left operand `x` is first promoted to `int`.  Both operands now have type `int`, so no other conversions, and the result of `x + y` has type `int`.  For the assignment, both sides have the same type so no conversion is applied

```
aux = y + z;
```

Looking at the `+` operator first, there is no promotion because both operands are at least as large as `int`.  Because the left operand is an `int` and the right operand is a `long int`, the left operand is converted to `long int` and the result of `y + z` has type `long int`.  This result is then converted to `int` for assignment to `aux`.